spring 3 with springdoc 2 - Failed to load remote configuration
I'm using spring boot 3.2.5 with org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.5.0 to power a simple API based on the OpenAPI spec.
My API is running fine (at /api/v1/mystuff), but when I try to load the swagger page at /webjars/swagger-ui/index.html#/,  I get the dreaded
"Failed to load remote configuration" error:

The browser JS logs indicate that it's calling http://localhost:8090/api-docs/swagger-config and getting a 404 error from that call.
Based on the docs I would expect the swagger page to be trying to call v3/api-docs, not /api-docs.  Out of curiosity I called /v3/api-docs but got a 404 from there too.
The security config looks like this:
@Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
      return http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
          .authorizeExchange((exchanges) -> exchanges.anyExchange().permitAll())
          .build();
    }


I have tried various things in application.yaml (including no springdoc config at all) but nothing seems to work.

Have you write any config in application.yml related to swagger? If possible please add more details about your spring config

@vik "I have tried various things in application.yaml (including no springdoc config at all)".  According to the springdoc documentation, it should work by simply adding the lib entry, with no config.

Have you tried hitting the URL http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui.html
